# Pulling/deleting an item from a nested array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Note: it's a Meteor project.
My schema looks like that:

```
{
    _id: 'someid'
    nlu: {
       data: {
            synonyms:[
                 {_id:'abc', value:'car', synonyms:['automobile']}
            ]
       }
    }
}
```

The schema is defined with `simple-schema`. Relevant parts:

```
 'nlu.data.synonyms.$': Object,
    'nlu.data.synonyms.$._id': {type: String, autoValue: ()=> uuidv4()},
    'nlu.data.synonyms.$.value': {type:String, regEx:/.*\S.*/},
    'nlu.data.synonyms.$.synonyms': {type: Array, minCount:1},
    'nlu.data.synonyms.$.synonyms.$': {type:String, regEx:/.*\S.*/},
```

I am trying to remove `{_id:'abc'}`:

```
Projects.update({_id: 'someid'},
                {$pull: {'nlu.data.synonyms' : {_id: 'abc'}}});
```

The query returns `1` (one doc was updated) but the item was not removed from the array. Any idea?

Comment: Just reproduced on a clean new project and I get with the code above `{ _id: 'jnL96cZ9ZY43m7vse', nlu: { data: { synonyms: [] } } }`

Edit: can you post a bit more code on how you check if the update suceeded?

Comment: Edit edit: do you use `aldeed:collection-2` and have set in your schema, that synonyms must not be empty, for instance using `minCount`  ?

Comment: Hmmm. There's another array in synonyms which has a minCount. I'll try removing that. Thanks!

Comment: @Jankapunkt: I removed the minCount in the nested array but still have the issue. For now I don't do much to check if it succeeds: check the return value (1) and look at the collection. I added more about the schema

Answer (score 0):

This is my insert query

```
db.test.insert({
    "_id": "someid",
    "nlu": {
       "data": {
            "synonyms": [
                 {
                    "_id": "abc"
                 },
                 {
                    "_id": "def"
                 },
                 10,
                 [ 5, { "_id": 5 } ] 
            ]
       }
    }
})
```

And here is my update

```
db.test.update(
    {
      "_id": "someid",
      "nlu.data.synonyms._id": "abc"
    },  
    {
      "$pull": {        
        "nlu.data.synonyms": {
          "_id": "abc"
        }
      }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem broke down to the `autoValue` parameter on your `_id` property.

This is [a very powerful feature](https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js#autovalue) to manipulate automatic values on your schema. However, it prevented from pulling as it had always returned a value, indicating that this field should be set.

In order to make it aware of the pulling, you can make it aware of an `operator` being present (as in cases of mongo updates).

Your `autoValue` would then look like:

```
'nlu.data.synonyms.$._id': {type: String, autoValue: function(){
  if (this.operator) {
    this.unset();
    return;
  }
  return uuidv4();
}},
```

Edit: Note the function here being not an arrow function, otherwise it losses the context that is bound on it by `SimpleSchema`.

It basically only returns a new `uuid4` when there is no operator present (as in insert operations). You can extend this further by the provided functionality (see the documentation) to your needs.

I just summarized my code to a reproducable example:

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';

const Projects = new Mongo.Collection('PROJECTS')

const ProjectSchema ={
  nlu: Object,
  'nlu.data': Object,
  'nlu.data.synonyms': {
    type: Array,
  },
  'nlu.data.synonyms.$': {
    type: Object,
  },
  'nlu.data.synonyms.$._id': {type: String, autoValue: function(){
    if (this.operator) {
      this.unset();
      return;
    }
    return uuidv4();
  }},
  'nlu.data.synonyms.$.value': {type:String, regEx:/.*\S.*/},
  'nlu.data.synonyms.$.synonyms': {type: Array, minCount:1},
  'nlu.data.synonyms.$.synonyms.$': {type:String, regEx:/.*\S.*/},
};

Projects.attachSchema(ProjectSchema);

Meteor.startup(() => {

  const insertId = Projects.insert({
    nlu: {
      data: {
        synonyms:[
          {value:'car', synonyms:['automobile']},
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  Projects.update({_id: insertId}, {$pull: {'nlu.data.synonyms' : {value: 'car'}}});

  const afterUpdate = Projects.findOne(insertId);
  console.log(afterUpdate, afterUpdate.nlu.data.synonyms.length); // 0
});
```

## Optional Alternative: Normalizing Collections

However there is one additional note for optimization.

You can work around this auto-id generation issue by normalizing synonyms into an own collection, where the mongo insert provides you an id. I am not sure how unique this id will be compared to `uuidv4` but i never faced id issues with that.

A setup could look like this:

```
const Synonyms = new Mongo.Collection('SYNONYMS');

const SynonymsSchema  = {
  value: {type:String, regEx:/.*\S.*/},
  synonyms: {type: Array, minCount:1},
  'synonyms.$': {type:String, regEx:/.*\S.*/},
};

Synonyms.attachSchema(SynonymsSchema);

const Projects = new Mongo.Collection('PROJECTS')

const ProjectSchema ={
  nlu: Object,
  'nlu.data': Object,
  'nlu.data.synonyms': {
    type: Array,
  },
  'nlu.data.synonyms.$': {
    type: String,
  },
};

Projects.attachSchema(ProjectSchema);

Meteor.startup(() => {

  // just add this entry once
  if (Synonyms.find().count() === 0) {
    Synonyms.insert({
      value: 'car',
      synonyms: ['automobile']
    })
  }

  // get the id
  const carId = Synonyms.findOne()._id;

  const insertId = Projects.insert({
    nlu: {
      data: {
        synonyms:[carId] // push the _id as reference
      }
    }
  });

  // ['MG464i9PgyniuGHpn'] => reference to Synonyms document
  console.log(Projects.findOne(insertId).nlu.data.synonyms); 

  Projects.update({_id: insertId}, {$pull: {'nlu.data.synonyms' : carId }}); // pull the reference

  const afterUpdate = Projects.findOne(insertId);
  console.log(afterUpdate, afterUpdate.nlu.data.synonyms.length);
});
```

I know this was not part of the question but I just wanted to point out that there are many benefits of normalizing complex document structures into separate collections:

- no duplicate data
- decouple data that is not intended to be bound (here: Synonyms could be also used independently from Projects)
- update referred documents once, all Projects will point to the very actual version (since it's a reference)
- finer publication/subscription handling => more control about what data flows over the wire
- reduces complex auto and default value generation
- changes in the referred collection's schema may have only few consequences for UI and functions that make use of the referrer's schema.

Of course this has also disadvantages:

- more collections to handle
- more code to write (more code = more potential errors)
- more tests to write (much more time to invest)
- sometimes you need to denormalize back for this one case out of 100
- you have to invest a lot of time in data schema design before starting to code

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Good catch for autoValue(). I changed to `if (this.operator === '$pull')...` as I still want autoValue to work for other operators such as `addToSet`. However, preventing autoValue from returning has a nasty side effect: All items are pulled from the array.

Comment: Re: normalization. I am trying to optimize performances, so I am bringing the synonyms collection as sub arrays in project documents. They are only needed in the context of the project so I am hoping it increases perf as the # of project grows

Comment: I retried the more complete example with more than one item on the array but it did not pull all items but maybe it's because in my example I pull by `value` match?